# vector subscript out of range Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to insert the output ofth elbp function (which is MAT) into new vector but I get: Vector subscript out of range error? Any suggestions?

```
vector <Mat> RefPyramids;
vector <Mat> LBPRefPyramids;
buildPyramid(PyramidDummy, RefPyramids, 3);
for (int PyramidIndex = 0; PyramidIndex <= 4; PyramidIndex++ )
{   
    Mat PramidLoopMat = RefPyramids[PyramidIndex];
    Mat LBPLoopMat;
    lbp::ELBP(PramidLoopMat, LBPLoopMat,  radius, neighbors);
    LBPRefPyramids[PyramidIndex] = LBPLoopMat;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how many elements are in each vector?  We really need an [mcve] to be able to help you.

Comment: @NathanOliver In this case I am expecting the vector sizes to be 4. RefPyramids vector has a size of 4 which are MAT s. I am just want to fill the LBPREFPyramid vector with the LBPLoopMats

Comment: Look at your for range then.  0 through 4 is 5 elements not 4.  Change `PyramidIndex <= 4` to `PyramidIndex < 4`

Comment: @Hertzial_97, if RefPyramids has a size of 4, then why is your loop running for PyramidIndex=4?

Comment: (0,1,2,3,4) is 5 elements.

Comment: Omg you guyz are right I need to have a coffee...

Answer (score 1):

You say (in a comment) that `RefPyramids` has size 4.  But your code violates that:

```
        for (int PyramidIndex = 0; PyramidIndex <= 4; PyramidIndex++ )
        {   
            Mat PramidLoopMat = RefPyramids[PyramidIndex];
```

You see, you're iterating over [0,1,2,3,4].  That `<=` should be `<`.